# Is there a distro specific to the LAMP stack?

Tags: apache-httpd, mysql, hosts, php5

I tried real hard to get LAMP stack working on my pop_os home pc, but could not get it working. Is there a distro in existence with the LAMP stack preinstalled which I can just add WordPress on top of. If possible I want to have my regular linux os that I use most of the time and this os that I load on a dual-boot setup when I need to work with wordpress.

I would much prefer a setup like this than, than one with windows.

Comment: You can search LAMP on distrowatch.com. You will probably find https://www.turnkeylinux.org/all, which even lists a turn-key Wordpress. On the other hand any mainstream Linux distro should make it easy to install Apache, MySQL (or MariaDB) and PHP (or Python, or whatever the P may stand for). You may be better off asking questions regarding the errors you encountered.

Comment: OK thank you for your comment for prosperities sake I have decided to answer this question. Maybe someone would find it useful again. Hope that is OK

Comment: Doesn’t the `wordpress` package available in pop_OS! work for you?

Comment: I tried installing it. I must have done something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

TurnKey Linux offers this functionality. It has a distro especially made for WordPress. It can be found [here](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/wordpress).